How to relate a gravitational plane wave to the GW from a binary system?
I have two different forms of gravitational waves that I am trying to reconcile.

A monochromatic GW with angular frequency $\Omega$ propagating in the $\textbf{n}$-direction can be expressed as

$$ h_{ij}(t,\textbf{x}) = \textbf{A}_{ij}(\textbf{n}) \cos \left (\Omega (t -\textbf{n}\cdot \textbf{x}) \right) \tag{1}$$
where $\textbf{n}$ is a unit vector and $i,j$ label the spatial indices. The amplitude term can be separated into the usual $+, \times$ polarisations:
$$\textbf{A}_{ij} = A^{+} \textbf{e}_{ij}^{+} +  A^{\times} \textbf{e}_{ij}^{\times}$$
for polarization tensors $\textbf{e}_{ij}^{+, \times} $ . For example see this textbook

The GW from a circular binary BH system is,

$$ h_{ij}(t, \textbf{n}) = h^{+}(t) \textbf{e}_{ij}^{+} + h^{\times}(t) \textbf{e}_{ij}^{\times} \tag{2}$$
with $h^{+}(t) = A_{\rm gw} a(\iota) \cos \Phi(t)$ and $h^{\times}(t) = A_{\rm gw} b(\iota) \sin \Phi(t)$ and $\iota$ is the source inclination, $\Phi(t)$ the GW phase and $a(\iota)$, $b(\iota)$ some functions of the inclination. For example, see Equation 1 and Equation 25 in this paper

I cannot see how to get from Equation (1) to Equation (2). The literature for Equation (2) points me towards this paper, but that is formulated in terms of changing mass quadrupoles of the binary system, rather than the plane wave form.
Any help much appreciated.

The first equation is the equivalent of a "linearly polarised" gravitational wave (GW). It consists of an arbitrary mixture of two polarisation states with no phase difference between them.
The GWs from a binary system are also a mixture of the two polarisation states, the relative amplitudes of which depend on the binary inclination. However, in this case, the polarisation components are 90 degrees out of phase and the GW could be said to be "elliptically polarised". $\Phi(t)$ is the equivalent of $\Omega t$ in the first equation and is roughly equal to $2\omega t$, where $\omega$ is the angular frequency of the binary system.
To go from the first equation to the second you just realise that the GWs from a binary consist of a superposition of two plane waves with the same frequency, but with orthogonal polarisations and 90 degrees out of phase.
The other trivial difference is that the second equation is not of a travelling wave. It only includes the $t$ dependence for the wave at some fixed spatial coordinate along the propagation direction.

Thanks for the answer. Is it possible to introduce a phase difference into the two polarisation states through an alternate definition of the basis tensors $\textbf{e}{ij}^{+,\times}$? i.e. such that the $\textbf{e}{ij}^{+,\times}$ in Equation 1 are not the same as the $\textbf{e}_{ij}^{+,\times}$ in Equation 2?

That is to say, can one start from Equation 1 and finish at Equation 2, or are they describing fundamentally different things?

@user1887919 there is nothing about the physics of binary systems in your first equation. The GWs from a binary system consists of two orthogonally polarised plane waves, with the same frequency but out of phase.

Ok I see. So what conditions, mathematically, do I have to impose on Equation 1 to arrive at Equation 2. I suppose it comes in the definition of $A_{ij}$?

@user1887919 I'm afraid I don't understand your comment. You cannot make a single cosine wave equal the sum of a sine wave and a cosine wave.
